# How do I purchase a label with Shippo via the Stripe integration?

Tags: shippo

I'm looking to integrate [Shippo with Stripe](https://goshippo.com/docs/stripe) to get shipping rates for my shop, and I want to purchase the label through Shippo.

Getting the rate from Shippo via the Stripe API is fine, then I make a call for the Rate using the object_id from the Stripe results.

But when I try to purchase the label through the Transaction request on from Shippo API, it says that it's rejected because it's a QUOTE, not a PURCHASE rate.

Here's the error message: *"The given Rate can't be purchased because it's object_purpose is not PURCHASE."*

How do I convert the Rate from a QUOTE to PURCHASE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you can't convert a Rate from QUOTE to PURCHASE on Shippo, so you'll have to create a shipping label through Shippo with the [single-call label creation process](https://goshippo.com/docs/single-call). You can pass in the carrier and service level tokens that you got from the Rate response to get what you need.

[See the full Shippo label generating example with Stripe.](https://goshippo.com/docs/stripe#create-stripe-shipping-labels) Here are the snippets you'll want to note:

```
# create Label with one API call - carrier_account, and servicelevel_token taken from the rate response.

transaction = shippo.Transaction.create(
    shipment = shipment,
    carrier_account = rate.carrier_account,
    servicelevel_token = rate.servicelevel_token
```